# XML Documentation for many Constants

Tags: c#, documentation, sandcastle

Is there a way to put an XML documentation *summary* tag on the same line as a constant in a class?

I have a class with a many many constant return values defined and having comment lines between each makes it a little difficult to read and maintain. (This same question would apply for enumeration values.)

The code below shows an example of how my code looks now. I'd like to keep it like this if there's a way.

```
public class MyUtilClass
{
    public static int  UTIL_SUCCESS         = 0;   // This is an example comment for success.
    public static int  UTIL_WARNING_LEVEL_1 = 1;   // This is an example comment for warning level 1.
    public static int  UTIL_WARNING_LEVEL_2 = 2;   // This is an example comment for warning level 2.
    public static int  UTIL_FAILED          = 3;   // This is an example comment for failure.
}
```

I'm using http://shfb.codeplex.com/ to generate my documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Use XML comments above each constant; they intellisense, and you can use them in automated documentation tools (including Sandcastle).  VS, Sandcastle and intellisense all expect the comments to be *above* the element they are referring to.

Comment: Yes that's how I've been doing it but I was specifically asking if anyone knew of a way to do it on the same line. Once you have a lot constants whether they be strings or numeric values, the list becomes difficult to maintain with the comments between them.

Comment: Not without breaking the tools I mentioned.  Put the constants into their own class if the number of them is getting too arduous.

Comment: Looks like that should be an `enum`, rather than a class with constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I think you have to include the XML doc above the thing it is documenting. You can, however, have the summary tags and their content on a single line:

```
/// <summary>Some content</summary>
public static int  UTIL_SUCCESS         = 0;
```